# How to make react-native-banner-carousel load images from API(asynchronous)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-banner-carousel/

It works fined with hardcoded images path.

**But this error happened if my images array is empty. It will show error as this image**

[image: error if images state is empty]

I guess it caused by empty array (please correct me if im wrong). The state.carousels yet to loading to state when it render.
How can I make it asynchronous, so it can load the images dynamically.

So this is my code.

### Dashboard.js

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.carouselFetch();
}
renderPage(image, index) {
    return (
        <View key={index}>
            <ImageFluid
                source={{ uri: image }}
                originalWidth={ 2500 }
                originalHeight= { 1000 }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
render(){
    const images = this.props.carousels;
    return(
        ......
        <Carousel
            autoplay
            autoplayTimeout={5000}
            loop
            index={0}
            showsPageIndicator={ false }
            pageSize={BannerWidth}
        >
        { images.map((image, index) => this.renderPage(image, index))}
        </Carousel>
        ......
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const carousels = state.carousel;
    return { carousels };
};
```

### CarouselActions.js

```
export const carouselFetch = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('API json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.Status === 'Fail') {
                return Promise.reject(response)
            }
            return response
         })
         .then(carousels => {
              carouselFetchSuccess(dispatch, carousels);
         })
         .catch(() => console.log("Error"));
     };
};

const carouselFetchSuccess = (dispatch, carousels) => {
    dispatch({
        type: CAROUSEL_FETCH_SUCCESS,
        payload: _.map(carousels.data, i => i.image_path)
    });
};
```

My Sample API json
[image]

The package required sample array method
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render(){
    const images = this.props.carousels;
    if (!images || images.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return(
        ......
        <Carousel
            autoplay
            autoplayTimeout={5000}
            loop
            index={0}
            showsPageIndicator={ false }
            pageSize={BannerWidth}
        >
        { images.map((image, index) => this.renderPage(image, index))}
        </Carousel>
        ......
    );
}
```

Don't render carousel when the image list length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

First use :

```
 const images = (  this.props.carousels || [] ).map( (image) => ( {
      value: carousels .name,
      label: carousels .id,
      order: carousels .data.
  } );
```

You have a simple array of objects not an nested array,  your response it's a simple res.data and not a res.carousel.data, if you use console.log(res) you will see your array, check that.

Comment: I updated my real response json which is nested and the package required sample array.. 

so your solution const images will put after render right? it will have (  this.props.carousels || [] ).map is not a function error

Comment: check first the response from json and them check the props you want to use.